# Turn off Chrome signin with Selenium Programmatically

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, chromium

I'm starting Chromium with Selenium. I would like to disable the
Allow Chrome sign-in (By turning this off, you can sign in to Google sites like Gmail without signing in to Chromium) option

[image]

I see the Default/Preferences file that the following thing should be change

```
"signin":{"DiceMigrationComplete":true,"allowed":true}
```

To this:

```
"signin":{
      "DiceMigrationComplete":true,
      "allowed":false,
      "allowed_on_next_startup":false
   },
```

I'm trying with these LocalStatePreferences.

```
chromeOptions.AddLocalStatePreference("singin.allowed", false);
chromeOptions.AddLocalStatePreference("singin.allowed_on_next_startup", false);
```

But they don't work. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Does it work if you just launch the browser in incognito?

Comment: Found the solutin. See my Answer

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to reach it is this:

```
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("signin.allowed_on_next_startup", false);
```

There was a typo in my previous **singing != signin**